# ¿ Que me muestra error de argumentos Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, react-native

Hola tengo el archivo `App.js` que se creó al hacer una aplicación por defecto en React Native `react-native init aplicación` .
El caso es que Visual Studio me muestra error de argumentos.

Este es el archivo:

```js
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 */

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android:
    'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

Me muestra dos errores en la siguiente sección, en el `Props`

```js
type Props/* aqui muestra error*/ = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> /* aquí tambien muestra error*/{
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Y los errores son los siguientes:

> "type aliases" solo se puede usar en un archivo .ts. [19, 6]
>
> "type arguments" solo se puede usar en un archivo .ts. {20, 44}

Mi pregunta es, ¿ Por que se muestran estos errores?

¿ Debo instalar extensiones en Visual Studio para trabajar mejor en React Native?

Los archivos .ts van relacionados con el audio y video, por lo que he podido leer.
¿ Pueden ayudarme con esto ?

Gracias

Comment: El error que te da es que ese código es Typescript, no Javascript. La declaración de tipos o el uso de genéricos no existen en Javascript

Comment: Vale @PabloLozano , me avisa de que eso solo puedo usarlo en archivos Typescript, archivos .ts .

Comment: De hecho, para usar la extensión correcta de React, podrías usar `.tsx`

Comment: La razón de por que te sale ese error es porque el ejemplo que te regala react-native, usa algo llamado `flow` puedes investigar un poco mas de ello, es una especie de Javascript tipado, algo más parecido a TypeScript, si quieres quitar el error, solo basta con eliminar el comentario que dice `@flow` y quitar las estructuras tipo diamante de tu código, funcionará de la misma forma

Comment: Muchas gracias @GermanAlzate , ya estaba investigando después del comentario de PabloLozano , pero tu comentario me ayuda a  buscar documentación más especifica. Aunque debo decirte, que apesar de quitar: `@format @flow` , sigue marcando error